# python-ldap simple_bind not strictly verifying password

Tags: python, ldap

I was playing around with Python's ldap module when I found that the ldap module's simple_bind()/ simple_bind_s() functions doesn't really do any strict authentication.

e.g.

```
import ldap

ldap_client = ldap.initialize("ldap://ldapserver.com")

ldap_login = 'abc'
password = 'passwd' # assume this is the right password

# scenario 1:
ldap_client.simple_bind_s(ldap_login, password) # Allows bind

# scenario 2:
password = 'passwd_kjasdk' # Incorrect password where suffix is incorrect
ldap_client.simple_bind_s(ldap_login, password) # Allows bind

# scenario 3:
password = 'kjasdk_passwd' # Incorrect password where prefix is incorrect
ldap_client.simple_bind_s(ldap_login, password) # Doesn't allow bind
```

Scenario 2 above clearly depicts that the bind function is simply allowing the login if password is matched in the initial characters.

Question is how to disallow/prevent 2nd scenario ?

Comment: Password verification is performed by the *server*, not by the client. If the server is permitting authentication with only a partial password match, there's nothing the client can do to resolve that.

Comment: @larsks I think you are right. Let me confirm this with our IT department. If they agree then I would ask you to put your comment as the answer which I will accept.